# How to store the result.xml file into database through audit to database in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have to store the result.xml file in database(MSSQL or MYSQL) which is        generated by a Jenkins job after successful build triggered. I came across the below plugin in Jenkins CI.

> "Audit to database plugin"

but it logged only the build information instead of specific xml/html file which is being generated by test-output directory in work space. Also I want to enable the data base connectivity only if its scheduled job trigger not for manual triggered.

Kindly let me know, is there any other plugin which can simplify this activity.